# arduino php serial with no serial monitor

Tags: php, linux, arduino

I'm having a bit of a situation I'm trying to control my arduino from a php site
and it is working fine but I need to keep the arduino app open as well as the serial monitor. Is there a way I can talk with the arduino without having the monitor open?

I have this working with the `php_serial_class` and just using fopen:

Basic version with fopen

```
<?

if (isset($_GET["action"])){


    $comPort = "/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131"; /*change to correct com port */

    if ($_GET['action']=='on') {


    $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
    fwrite($fp, 'a'); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);

}

if ($_GET['action']=='off') {


    $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
    fwrite($fp, 'b'); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);
    }


}


?>

<body>
<h1>Controllering the Arduino from php</h1>

    <a href="controller.php?action=on">Turn ON!!!</a>
    <a href="controller.php?action=off">Turn OFF</a>


</body>
```

THIS IS with php_class

```
<?

include "php_serial.class.php";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("a\r");

$serial->deviceClose();


?>
```

should be on

Comment: You shouldn't need anything open. What problems are you seeing?

Comment: If i leave the serial mon open everything works fine but when i dont keep it open i get nothing site just spins

Comment: i heav seen places saying to connect the 5v to the reset with a 100ohm res. when i do this LED blinks 3 times and turns off

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to read (fgets) just after you open the port... maybe arduino is waiting for you to read before it reads your commands.

Also, take a look at http://php.net/dio